# How Can I Prevent Gmail from Opening a New Tab when I Switch Accounts?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-workspace

It seems that about 2 weeks ago, Gmail began *always* opening a new tab (in Chrome at least) *every* time I switch Accounts.

Previously it only opened new tabs when I logged into a new account, but if I closed down to 1 tab, and switched between accounts, I could stay in the same tab.

Does anyone know of a setting in Gmail to keep the same tab when switching accounts?

NOTE: I know about opening links in new windows and tabs, and this *not* what I am asking - this question is *specific* only to switching accounts in Gmail.

Comment: There is an extension for this feature [OpenHERE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/panlnaemgbbdbmppblcdgjjamkopjcak), but unfortunately it doesn't work in this situation [I've notified the author about it].  If you are already logged into both accounts, you could change [https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox) to [https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1) (and vice versa) in the address bar manually.

Comment: @rishimaharaj thanks for the helpful hints, but I'll settle for no less than the way it *used* to work - switch accounts, stay in same tab.

Comment: I can confirm that the same problem exists with Firefox. I always had one tab 'pinned as app-tab' and it was easy to change between the 2 Gmail accounts I am using. For the time being I now have 2 tabs pinned.

Comment: Perhaps Google made an executive decision and decided that they want accounts to run in separate tabs all the time?  I have to say I could live with it, now I've become somewhat accustomed to it.  I am not sure I totally dislike knowing each of my 3 tabs have each of my most-oft-used 3 email inboxen ready to go.

Comment: It's been some time since I posted this - and I admit now that I've just become used to it; and I don't mind it at all now - it seems totally normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you need, but you can drag the "Add Account" Button to your address bar, works for me on Firefox.

Comment: YES and no.  YES because it does just what I asked for: once I'm logged into multiple accounts, I can keep it all happening in 1 tab (works for me in Chrome) - and, well, I have to admit, I've kind of settled into having a tab open for each email account, and tabbing between them instead of "post"-ing between them.  SO  YOU WIN! Marked your help as the answer - well done!

Comment: NOTE: I get what I wanted by dragging the "Add Account" button to *the same tab I was already in*

Comment: You can also drag other account icon istead of 'add account' button to open gmail for a given account directly.

Answer (score -1):

For Google Chrome users: You can follow the steps below to remove that account, then add it back on, and after step # 4, ensure you choose NO when it asks you to create a new Profile for it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I got it, I just solved the issue. You have to switch with the profile icon on the webpage itself instead of the button on the browser task bar (the icon next to the 3 dots icon).